# NextJS SSR SSG after user sign in or while updating the cart

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I've some experience with ReactJS but now I’m trying NextJS, I’ve a question that keeps coming up in my head regarding the SSR/SSG,
for an e-commerce app, if all pages (/products, /product, ….) are SSGed or SSRed what happens after the user sign in and I need to show his name and image in the topbar on all routes, how does the pages get pre-rendered or cached at this point?
the same question when talking about the cart that keeps changing when adding/removing items from it.
If NextJS will re-SSR on every route first visit after signing or cart update, does that mean a user who signed in might get a slower navigation than the one who is not?

Comment: what you can do is authenticate the user and manage the shopping cart on the client side

Comment: @Beloved, do you mean that some parts of a SSRed page can be manipulated on the client side?

Comment: what i mean is you can fetch products with SSR or SSG and manage cart and other stuff on client side that's what i have always done. by example your topbar can fetch the authenticated user with swr, redux or context on client side and for private pages, you can check if user is authenticated on client side. you can do the same with cart

Comment: Thanks a lot, I get it know! This was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-render the content on your server (using SSR or SSG) and hydrate after on the client.

In a lot of cases the profile info doesn't need to be pre-rendered cause is not relevant for the SEO. same way as the cart which is private for each user. On that cases you can pre-render the pages with only the general info, and then hydrate with the profile content or the cart.

This is an [example](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/with-nextjs) of that using SWR, a fetching library developed by vercel.